# What word would best describe this scenario (giving a true but evasive answer)?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, synonyms, american-english, pejorative-language

What could be the word to best describe this following scenario:

> Parent 1: Why did you give the child a high-sugar drink when I specifically asked you not too?
>
> Parent 2: It's fine everybody, the drink was analysed by our experts and found not to have any caffeine at all.

Would it be red-herring? Obfuscation? Non sequitur?

Comment: It sounds like an appeal to authority.

Comment: Sounds like a non sequitur to me. Caffeine and sugar are different substances, so the absence of one has no relevance to the presence or absence of the other.